# Wiring 2 pull chain operated lights in series

Tags: electrical, light-fixture

How do I wire 2 pull chain operated lights in series from the same single power source so that both lights are powered and will work independently. There will be no other switch on the line and power source is coming from a nearby power outlet.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What do you mean by "in series"? (A diagram would help.) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Answer (score 2):

You will not be wiring the two light fixtures in series. In fact you will be wiring them up in parallel from a single power feed. Since the power feed is always on make sure to have the breaker off before attempting to do any connections.

The pull chains on each light assembly will allow independent control of each light.